# How to migrate a custom site theme & layout pages from Staging-->Prod

Tags: 2013, migration, solution-package, custom-masterpage, theme

I am wondering how to best migrate a custom theme (custom master page, layouts, including image and css assets etc) from one environment to another in SharePoint 2013 (STAGING-->PRODUCTION).

The existing production site already has content and a theme, so I can't do a sitecopy, I can only selectively copy the required files across.

Not sure how to best approach this, do I use a WSP, or Powershell, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create WSP for your custom modifications, deploy that WSP to your production environment and use features to activate the required functionality where it is required.